# authentication not working in php file

Tags: php, sql

i have a login system, which redirect user to his workplace after login and i have set the logout button and to clear session i have done this:

This code check for session, which is created after login:

this code in included in workplace area after login.

UPDATE 2:

```
 <?php
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/ModelBase/connect/auth.php');
 ?>
```

but after login ; i get this error when i upload it to host:

Re-UPDATE 2:
Error after updating require_once statement again:

```
Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/data/19/1/86/59/1901711/user/2069354/htdocs/xxxxxx/connect/auth.php' (include_path='.:/usr/services/vux/lib/php') in /data/19/1/86/59/1901711/user/2069354/htdocs/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxx/index.php on line 2
```

Found the solution myself.. Thanks everyone anyways..

just was missing 1 part of path folder and that fixed up all..

NOTE:  When i use this same process over localhost it never shows any error. what should i do ?

Comment: one server is windows.... other one is linux.

Comment: Try to provide `DOCUMENT_ROOT` and then give full path

Comment: Does the file "/data/19/1/86/59/1901711/user/2069354/htdocs/MainProject/xxxxxx/connect/auth.php" exist?

Comment: @DavidHoude Yes that exists !

Comment: That's the reason we use `require_once` so we can have a error if something goes wrong in getting the file. So just check the error , debug & solve it !!

Comment: See itachi's comment, and change ..\connect\auth to ../connect/auth

Comment: @DavidHoude i have done that..changed the format.. but still new error.

Comment: @devilcrab - Update your question with code you have tried.

Comment: Updated, please have a look.

Comment: `require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/ModelBase/connect/auth.php');` Dude do some basic debugging!

Comment: i can't -1 it but due to 125 rep restriction or i would have... :\  i told its not working.. read before posting !

Comment: here is the error that i get next when i do that:  Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/data/19/1/86/59/1901711/user/2069354/htdocs/xxxxxx/connect/auth.php' (include_path='.:/usr/services/vux/lib/php') in /data/19/1/86/59/1901711/user/2069354/htdocs/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxx/index.php on line 2

Comment: itachi already raised the issue. But is it possible you named the file Auth.php (capital letter?). Your home server might be Windows wich is case-insensitive and your server is linux (which is case sensitive).

Answer (score 1):

you have error in include file path try

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/ModelBase/connect/auth.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

> require_once('$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']./ModelBase/connect/auth.php');

To:

> require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/ModelBase/connect/auth.php');

Done:)

Comment: Already tried got a big error.. :P

Comment: Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/data/19/1/86/59/1901711/user/2069354/htdocs/xxxxxx/connect/auth.php' (include_path='.:/usr/services/vux/lib/php') in /data/19/1/86/59/1901711/user/2069354/htdocs/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxx/index.php on line 2

Comment: ok, ty this: require_once('/ModelBase/connect/auth.php');

Comment: i have updated my post with correct answer ~!